# Is $K$ here a subfield of $\Bbb C$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

In Jürgen Neukirch's "Algebraic Number Theory", page 5.

> An algebraic number field is a finite field extension $K$ of $\Bbb Q$. The elements of $K$ are called algebraic numbers.

Is $K$ here a subfield of $\Bbb C$?

Comment: Subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, finite dimensional $K$-algebra, commutative subring of $M_n(\mathbb{Q})$, fraction field of a lattice in $\mathbb{C}^n$ which is a ring, there are many ways to think to number fields. The first theorem is $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ whenever $\alpha$ is algebraic

Comment: Number fields can be embedded into $\mathbb{C}$ but these embeddings are not unique. It's sometimes useful to think about them.